# Is it possible to load PHP asynchronously with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP page `view.php` which includes another PHP page `api.php`
Now when a user requests some file like `view.php?id=xyz` a request is sent to `api.php?id=xyz` and some data is fetched and displayed in view.php

As this happens the page load time increases severely as `api.php` request some data from remote server.

Is it possible to load the whole view.php and then on user's click on a button request api.php?

Here's what I want to do:

**view.php**

```
<?php
// Load Some Content
echo '<div class="click">Click Here</div>';
// Don't Load The Following Div Unless User Clicks The Above Div
echo '<div class="load">';
include 'api.php';
echo '</div>';
// Load Some Content
?>
```

I want to load the whole `view.php` without loading `api.php` but it should be included in `view.php` and once user clicks on `Click Here` div it should load `api.php`

Comment: ajax is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to you an AJAX request to asynchronously request the data from `api.php`. I would change my `view.php` file to output a simple form like this:

```
<div class="click" onclick="fetch">Click Here</div>
<div id="load"></div>
```

Then using JS, fetch the data from the `api.php` resource.

```
<script>
    function fetch(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'api.php', true);

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                //assuming response from api.php is html
                document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        };

        request.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below AJAX script to handle it. You must include jquery library to work.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "api.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {id:xyz},
    success: function (response) {
       // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)   
         $('#divid').html(response); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to load data from api.php.

**view.php**

```
<?php
// Load Some Content
echo '<div class="click" onclick="getData()">Click Here</div>';
// Don't Load The Following Div Unless User Clicks The Above Div
echo '<div class="load" id="loadFromApi">';
echo '</div>';
echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>';
echo '<script>';
echo 'function getData(){';
echo '$("#loadFromApi").load("api.php");';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
// Load Some Content
?>
```

Comment: Why isn't it working with a slash? I have itegrated it as: `$("#loadFromApi").load("/api.php");`

Comment: If the file api.php is on the root folder of your web application ( which means http://mywebsite.com/api.php ) it should work fine but if not it will not work you have to specify the sub directory ( http://mywebsite.com/dir/api.php) you have to request (/dir/api.php)

Comment: api.php is in the root directory but view.php is URL optimised for SEO. So view.php is like /view/someurl/otherurl

Comment: Check your htaccess file in the root directory and make sure you can access the api.php normally ( make sure yourwebsite.com/api.php is actually working in browser )

Comment: The url is muzic.asia/api.php and api.php will not work without view.php